# Stack Overflow-like tag selector for Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to use tags for a model in my Rails application, and I'd like to have the same kind of tag selection mechanism that Stack Overflow has when asking a question. I.e. I type in 'rails' and it drops down a list of tags that include 'rails', and I can go on to add more tags from there. Is there a plugin that can do this?

I'm comfortable putting together the tag model and migrations myself, that isn't an issue. I just need something to handle the AJAX and javascript. I'm using prototype and Rails 2.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar requirement and used the following: http://loopj.com/2009/04/25/jquery-plugin-tokenizing-autocomplete-text-entry/

It worked very well.

Good luck

Comment: Looks good, not crazy about jQuery but I'll try it out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the tag selector SO use: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/ it uses JQuery which you can get to work in conjunction with prototype.